# Re-run a running script based on cronjob

Tags: shell, video, cron, mplayer

I have a script that plays a local video continuously file using `mplayer` on fullscreen using this command:

`mplayer -loop 0 -fs /path/to/movie.mp4`

However, movie.mp4 is being downloaded from my webserver when its not available. The movie on my server is going to change every now and then, so I want to compare the size of my video with the video on the webserver. Now that is not a problem, and I have that script already.

What I want is, when there is a new video, that it downloads and removes the old one (got this working), and then replays that video using the same mplayer command.

How would I do this?

Comment: So which part exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need to have mplayer work constantly, and then playing a new video when it is available. I can't think of a way myself to have this go smooth

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have mplayer work constantly, and then playing a new video
> when it is available. I can't think of a way myself to have this go
> smooth

Downloading the new video to a temporary file and `mv temporary /path/to/movie.mp4` should play the new video as soon as the current play is finished.
See also: [Is it possible to delete an MP3 file currently played in mplayer?](https://superuser.com/a/663310/227548)